# Indenting Labels and Checkboxes, with the checkbox outside the label and long labels

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately I'm stuck using an old program to generate forms, but I can fiddle with the CSS. The program generates the following html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_QStrategy_QV03_CV02" id="_Q2_C1" class="mrMultiple" style="" value="V02">
<label for="_Q2_C1">
<span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Defining the finance operating model to align with and support the execution of the organisation’s broader strategy. A finance operating model is a description of how an the finance function’s people, process and technology interacts internally and externally to deliver products and services.</span>
</label>
```

The label long and wraps over to the next line, with the text on the next line directly under the checkbox. How can I make it so that the wrapped text is indented?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: A screenshot would help, too. I can't quite work out what effect you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float elements with a width specified to them

```
label{float:left;width: 75%;}
input[type="checkbox"]{float:left;width:20px}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/q6xEY/)

Comment: I'm marking this down simply because it doesn't work as soon as you have multiple instances of this type of choice - not uncommon in forms. The content starts to wrap around the right-hand column.

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```
.mrMultipleText
{
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}
.mrMultiple
{
    float:left;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sx5S/1)

Comment: This indents all the text, not just the wrapped text.